# How to add substitution tags to the subject of the email in SendGrid using the xsmtp-api with the php library

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am trying to set up the name of my client in the subject of the email.
This is very crucial for my application, and from what I've read in the [SendGrid API docs](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html)
it is quite possible!.

> Info - Substitution tags will work in the Subject line as well as the body of the email.

The problem is that I dob't seem to manage to accomplish this.
At first I though that perhaps it's because I am already using the %name% sub within the body of the email, so I've created a new substitution parameter name %nameSubject%,
and yet, it won't work.

I use the following code, and the rest of the parameters within the email are workigng just fine:

```
    /**
    @description Wrapper method in order to handle possible exception due to programmer\ maintainer errors.
    A part of a small wrapper class that I have designed to allow 1-line comfortable use of the the SendGrid and transport classes.
   @returns int - 1, unless there is an internal error, or an exception thrown
    */
public function execute(){
    if(!class_exists('SendGrid') || !class_exists('SendGrid\Mail')){
        throw new exception('Dependency exception SendGrid or SendGrid\Mail are not included');
    }
    if(!isset($this->mailingList) && empty($this->mailingList) || sizeof($this->mailingList) == 0){
        throw new exception('Cannot send an email to an empty set of addresses');
    }
    if(!isset($this->subject, $this->body) || empty($this->subject) || empty($this->body)){
        throw new exception('Cannot send an email without both a subject and a body');
    }

    $sendgrid = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_USER, SENDGRID_PASSWORD);

    // $this->importMailList();
    foreach($this->mailingList as $key => $val) {   
        $this->mail->addTo($key, $val);
    }
    $this->mail->
    setFrom($this->fromMail)-> 
    setSubject($this->subject)->
    setText($this->text)->
    setHtml($this->body);
    if(preg_match('/%name%/', $this->body) && !array_filter($this->mailingList, 'is_int') ){
        $this->mail->addSubstitution("%name%", array_values($this->mailingList));
    }
    return $sendgrid->smtp->send($this->mail);

}
```

Any help is much appriciated!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution tags should be set individually for the subject or body. Try something like this:

```
$this->mail->
setFrom($this->fromMail)-> 
setSubject($this->subject)->addSubstitution("%name%", array("Harry", "Bob"))->
...
```

You can replace the example array I used with your own array values. We also have some PHP code examples showing substitution tags in our docs as well. (http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html#-Using-Substitutions)

Comment: Thank a lot sir,
the problem is that I am using this functionality as part of a rather complicated cron auto mailer if I may say so myself.

Must I use the precise syntax, or is it enough to call 
mail->addSubstitution() once after adding a subject, and once again after adding the body, in that order?.