# Sendgrid Substitution not working in PHP API

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

I tried to send mail using sendgrid template and getting mail successfully but substitution not working.

```
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(SEND_GRID_API);
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->addTo($to, $first_name.' '.$last_name);
$email->setFrom("info.kickingworld@gmail.com", "Kicking World");
$email->setSubject($subject);
$email->addSubstitution("[Customer]", $first_name.' '.$last_name);
$email->addSubstitution("[Sender_Name]", "Kicking World");
$email->addSubstitution("[Sender_Address]", '');
$email->addSubstitution("[Sender_City]", '');
$email->addSubstitution("[Sender_State]", '');
$email->addSubstitution("[Sender_Zip]", '');
$email->addSubstitution("<%asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url%>", '');
$email->addSubstitution("[Weblink]", '');
$email->addHeader('X-Sent-Using', 'SendGrid-API');
$email->addHeader('X-Transport', 'web');
$email->setTemplateId($template);
$response = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

getting mail **[Customer]** not dynamic substitution value.

Comment: Try like this ```$full_name= $first_name.' '.$last_name;``` then pass to this line ```$email->addSubstitution("[Customer]", $full_name);```

Comment: @kishor10d not working.

Comment: This may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132427/how-to-add-substitution-tags-to-the-subject-of-the-email-in-sendgrid-using-the-x